# How do I resolve “Failed to execute goal on project: could not resolve dependencies"

Tags: dependencies, maven-3, pom.xml

I am new to **maven**. I have using `maven 3.0.5`.

When ever I do

> $mvn clean install

I am getting error below.

```
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2:00.004s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 03 15:27:20 IST 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 29M/134M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project airavata-common-utils: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.airavata:airavata-common-utils:jar:0.9-SNAPSHOT:
 Failed to collect dependencies for [xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1 (compile),
 org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.5.0 (compile), xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.3_7 (compile), xpp5:xpp5:jar:1.2.6 (compile), 
xsul:xsul:jar:2.10.5_b (compile), xsul5-ogce:xsul5-2007-02-27:jar:1 (compile), 
org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.5.1 (compile),
 commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.2 (compile), org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.9.1.0 (compile), org.apache.derby:derbyclient:jar:10.9.1.0 (compile), org.apache.derby:derbynet:jar:10.9.1.0 (compile), org.apache.derby:derbytools:jar:10.9.1.0 (compile),
 org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.22 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.7 (test), org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.2 (test),
 org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.2 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.3_7: Could not transfer artifact xpp3:xpp3:pom:1.1.3_7 from/to ogce.m2.all (http://community.ucs.indiana.edu:9090/archiva/repository/ogce.m2.all): Access denied to: http://community.ucs.indiana.edu:9090/archiva/repository/ogce.m2.all/xpp3/xpp3/1.1.3_7/xpp3-1.1.3_7.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:                                              
    [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :airavata-common-utils
```

How do I resolve the error **“Failed to execute goal on project: could not resolve dependencies."**?

Basically I am not able to download dependencies.

Comment: It mentions about `Access denied`. Do you have a permission to access that repository?

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk  No. previously I was able to download and build it without any hassel

Answer (score 0):

@vijju - Either change Maven's settings.xml to not point to http://community.ucs.indiana.edu:9090/archiva/repository/ or fix your login problem.